# How to enumerate network interfaces

Tags: google-chrome-extension

getNetworkInterfaces will gives all interfaces but i am stuck in filtering the network interfaces from  **networkIfaceArray**

chrome.system.network.getNetworkInterfaces(function (**networkIfaceArray**)
   {

}

Please help, Sarath s

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You have to give a function and the function will get called with an array of objects, of which the format is [specified in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_network#method-getNetworkInterfaces).

Comment: networkIfaceArray will gives all the data properly,but i am stuck in filtering that data to individual interface values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this? Just iterate through the returned interfaces and get the data from each one?

```
chrome.system.network.getNetworkInterfaces(function(networkIfaceArray){
    for(var i = 0; i < networkIfaceArray.length; i++){
        var iface = networkIfaceArray[i];
        console.log("name : "+iface.name+
                        " ; address : "+iface.address+
                        " ; prefixLength : "+iface.prefixLength);
    }
});
```